# Pronouncing dollar amount with System.Speech.Synthesis

Tags: .net, currency, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

If I run this in the Speech Synthesizer in .NET

```
 phrase.AppendText("Our cost is");
 phrase.AppendText(9.ToString("c"));
```

It pronounces it as:

`dollars nine dot zero zero`

The docmentation [`SayAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.sayas.aspx) enumeration in System.Speech.Synthesis says:

> > numerates the content types for the speaking of elements such as times, dates, and currency.

Great! except the enumeration doesn't actually have anything related to Currency! Just dates, numbers and spelling out of words.

It looks like in Speech Server 2007 they *used* to have both telephone numbers and currency but it's gone now!

I realize I could probably have written a RegEx to parse it out in the time it took me to write this question - but if there's a way to do this in a better way I'd love to find out how.

Comment: When I worked with a few TTS-es back then, I had to do these kind of custom text parsing depending on the TTS. You have only this approach left I worry. A good starter http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-numbers-to-words Or may be this http://forums.exchangecore.com/topic/684-convert-number-to-words-c-console-application/

Comment: it just stuck me as wierd they took it out. must be some complicated situations with foreign currencies or languages they didn't want to deal with. it's really not hard to parse out $3.50 to 'three fifty' for US locale - or perhaps they figured it was too easy and not worthy of API support